# Using DjangoPaypal for Subscriptions not working

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-paypal

Im have used Django-PayPal for one time payment and its work good. Now i want to convert it into Subscription that will automatically resubscribe the package on same day of next month or next year.
This is the code of one time payment which is working fine:

```
 
paypal_dict = {
                    'business': mailpaypal,
                    'amount':  request.POST.get('amount'),
                    'item_name': 'Order {}'.format(pack.packagename),
                    'invoice': 'Package'+str(request.POST.get("package_id"))+str(genralsetting_views.systemtimezone(request)),
                    'custom': str(transactionid)+"_Package_"+str(request.POST.get("package_id"))+'_'+str(genralsetting_views.systemtimezone(request))+'_'+str(endtime)+ '_' + str(viddd)+'_'+str(request.session['id'])+'_'+str(request.session['currency']),
                    'currency_code': GeneralSetting.objects.get(userid__usertype="superadmin").currency,
                     "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri('/') + 'SubscriptionPaypalIPN',
                    "return": request.build_absolute_uri('/') + 'index',
                    "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri('/') + 'RegistrationPackages',
                }


                form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
                return render(request, 'Vendor/Packages/RegistrationPackages/paypalpayment.html', {'cur':GeneralSetting.objects.get(userid__usertype="superadmin").currency,"session": request.session, 'form': form,"Data":data})
```

In the Django-Paypal documentation they showed the way to do subscription,as shown below:

```
paypal_dict = {
    "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
    "business": 'receiver_email@example.com',
    "a3": "9.99",                      # monthly price
    "p3": 1,                           # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
    "t3": "M",                         # duration unit ("M for Month")
    "src": "1",                        # make payments recur
    "sra": "1",                        # reattempt payment on payment error
    "no_note": "1",                    # remove extra notes (optional)
    "item_name": "my cool subscription",
    "notify_url": "http://www.example.com/your-ipn-location/",
    "return": "http://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
    "cancel_return": "http://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",
}

# Create the instance.
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")

# Output the button.
form.render()
```

I have write the code same as they said in documentation

```
paypal_dict = {
                    "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
                    "business": mailpaypal,
                    "a3": "9.99",  # monthly price
                    "p3": 1,  # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
                    "t3": "M",  # duration unit ("M for Month")
                    "src": "1",  # make payments recur
                    "sra": "1",  # reattempt payment on payment error
                    "no_note": "1",  # remove extra notes (optional)
                    "item_name": "my cool subscription",
                         "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri('/') + 'SubscriptionPaypalIPN',
                    "return": request.build_absolute_uri('/') + 'index',
                    "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri('/') + 'RegistrationPackages',
                }
                form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")

                return render(request, 'Vendor/Packages/RegistrationPackages/paypalpayment.html', {'cur':GeneralSetting.objects.get(userid__usertype="superadmin").currency,"session": request.session, 'form': form,"Data":data})
```

But when i click on subscribe button ,paypal says "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

when i click on subscribe button it redirects to this link "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" , while when doing one time payment it redirects to this link "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=8F359638A8728725A&useraction=commit&mfid=159438098_a982*3bb48 "

Can anyone tell me the solution to how to do the subscription with paypal-django?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens for a number of different reasons.

1- Are you using a sandbox to test ? if yes, did you use the appropriate email ids in the python dict as well as during login ? You need to use a sandbox business account in python dict and personal sandbox account email to login during making the test payment.

2- Did your sandbox accounts you setup have the correct currency configuration ?